# Element Repositioning using only CSS(Volusion Details)

Tags: html, css, volusion

I'm attempting to rearrange elements on  a Volusion store for my employer. The products page we currently have looks like [This](http://www.fitnessfinders.net/ProductDetails.asp?ProductCode=151-perfectattendance&Click=35258)

I've been tasked with moving the details box 
(containing "Nothing says "I'm ready to learn!"), up and to the right, to align with the price box.
The box is a table contained in a hierarchy of nested tables, at roughly the same "depth" in a different branch.

I don't have access to the HTML for the page, only a template html file that generates menus and footers along with the relevant CSS. Some JS exists on the site but since I lack experience with it, I'm hesitant to get into it.

Because of the table-and-div structure, and the fact that I cannot edit the HTML, I'm left with tweaking stylesheets and possibly some javascript. My issue is this: How, using only these tools, can I take an element in one container and reposition it relative to elements in another container? I've tried 

`Position:Relative; 
left:some percentage;
top:some negative percentage;`

Which, for a single page, I can get to look quite good, but if I allow others to load the page it falls apart completely, due mostly to the fact that the container for the element I'm moving is calculated based on screen width, and the container for the destination is calculated with the width minus a constant value(the image for the product).

My employer is willing to accept that the arrangement won't be perfect, they know Volusion is <strike>the devil</strike> complex. But it's important to them that their products display all relevant information "above-the-fold".  Obviously I've not found any sort of answers on this. I don't find all that many people who have to edit a webpage without access to the raw code, because that's stupid. Worse still, moving an element to align with a completely different container is just bad policy as I gather, but its what I'm being asked to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do this on Volusion is with javascript. You do not have access to the HTML for the product page and given that it is built with tables there is no way to move the product description area up with CSS.

You need to use javascript to detach and append the product description box below the product details area.

Comment: I think to run that I'd have to put the script in the site-wide template. I'm not sure but that seems likely to incur performance issues as it loads a pointless script on every page. 

Or is it much simpler than I'm thinking?

Comment: Yes, it does have to be in the global template (or in javascript linked to from there). Because all product pages in Volusion have a similar structure both in terms of the URL and the html structure, you can start with an if statement to ensure it is a product page to at least not run the whole thing elsewhere. While it does slow things down somewhat, you do not have a choice. It's the only way to do it on Volusion.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way around it... You need access to the HTML files. You could do it with absolute positioning but that is not good practice.

Because you are working with a template; if you change the arrangement of that page then all of the other product pages will follow. So the reason you can't find the HTML is probably because you are looking for a .php containing html..

I suggest to spend time understanding the template or get a volution expert.

Comment: I grasp the template pretty well, and I understand that the product pages are all influenced the same, that's rather the point. I was simply trying to see if there was a trick I'd  not heard of that might achieve the goal.  

Volusion won't help, I'm trying to circumvent their markup in the first place.

Thanks for the honest appraisal though, kind of confirming my suspicions. I think I'm just gonna have to tell them its not feasible.

Comment: A further note after rereading your comment: It's not a failure to *find* the html, its that access is restricted, Volusion generates the page based on code they don't give users access to. I can only override it.